# How do I stop my data from being plotted as fragmented?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, netcdf

I'm trying to plot data from a NetCDF file onto a world map. However, everytime I do, I get a plot that has issues with it (see screenshot). It should be fully coloured as the min and max encompass the full range of data, and the lat and lon print out as they should. It plots perfectly well in ncview, but not in python. What can I do to get the data to plot correctly on the map? (A.K.A Where have I mucked up?)

Code is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.netcdf as S
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import *
import pyproj as py
#import various libraries needed

q = input("Enter month of data wanted (1 = Jan, 12 = Dec): ")
#make sure that input is valid (integer 1 - 12) - Warn if not and close program
if q>12:
    print "You have not entered a valid month!"
elif q<1:
    print "You have not entered a valid month!"
elif isinstance( q, ( int, long ) ) == False:
    print "You're just trying to annoy me now, aren't you?"
    #if all is good, proceed to getting data
else:


qq = q-1
f = S.netcdf_file('aerocom.HadGEM3-A-GLOMAP.AEROCOM-A2-CTRL.monthly.sconcbc.2006.nc','r')
#read in the file as a netcdf file into a filehandle with data
bc = f.variables['sconcbc'][qq,:,:]
lon1 = f.variables['lon'][:]
lat = f.variables['lat'][:]
bc, lon = addcyclic(bc, lon1)

print lon
for x in np.nditer(lon, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if x>180 :
        x[...] = x-360
print lon
print lat       

# use low resolution coastlines.
map = Basemap(projection='cyl',lat_0=0.,lon_0=0,resolution='l')
map.fillcontinents #(color='grey',lake_color='white')
# draw the edge of the map projection region 
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
#draw lat/lon grid lines every 30 degrees.
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,30)) 
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30))

#make grid on world map from the long/lat in the data (shape of bc)
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
    #create array for colourbar and contour pattern
    Y =[1e-15,1e-14,1e-13,5e-13,1e-12,3e-12,5e-12,7e-12,9e-12,1e-11,3e-11,5e-11,6e-11,7e-11,9e-11,1e-10,3e-10,5e-10,7e-10,9e-10,1e-9,2e-9,3e-9,5e-9,7e-9,9e-9,1e-8,2e-8,4e-8,6e-8,8e-8]
#make those the x and y axis, but in map form
x, y =map(lon,lat)


plt.clf()
my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('CMRmap')


cs = map.contourf(x,y,bc,levels = Y,cmap=my_cmap,locator=mpl.ticker.LogLocator())


# set colourbar with location and size, with labels.


plt.colorbar(cmap=my_cmap,orientation="horizontal",shrink=0.5)

font = {'family' : 'serif',
    'color'  : 'black',
    'weight' : 'bold',
    'size'   : 24,
    }
#add plot details
plt.title('Black Carbon monthly average surface concentrations for %s/2006 in kgm-3'%(q) ,fontdict=font)
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.75)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
#show plot
plt.show()
```

Screenshot:

[image: Black Carbon monthly average surface concentrations for 9/2006]

```
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (12 currently)
    lat = 145 ;
    lon = 192 ;
    bnds = 2 ;
variables:
    double time(time) ;
            time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
            time:units = "days since 1850-01-01" ;
            time:calendar = "360_day" ;
            time:axis = "T" ;
            time:long_name = "time" ;
            time:standard_name = "time" ;
    double time_bnds(time, bnds) ;
    double lat(lat) ;
            lat:bounds = "lat_bnds" ;
            lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
            lat:axis = "Y" ;
            lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
            lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
    double lat_bnds(lat, bnds) ;
    double lon(lon) ;
            lon:bounds = "lon_bnds" ;
            lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
            lon:axis = "X" ;
            lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
            lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
    double lon_bnds(lon, bnds) ;
    float sconcbc(time, lat, lon) ;
            sconcbc:standard_name = "mass_concentration_of_black_carbon_dry_
aerosol_in_air" ;
            sconcbc:long_name = "Surface concentration BC" ;
            sconcbc:units = "kg m-3" ;
            sconcbc:original_name = "mo: m01s77i008" ;
            sconcbc:cell_methods = "time: mean" ;
            sconcbc:history = "2012-04-18T10:44:22Z altered by CMOR: replace
d missing value flag (-1.07374e+09) with standard missing value (1e+20)." ;
            sconcbc:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
            sconcbc:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
            sconcbc:associated_files = "gridspecFile: gridspec_REALM_fx_HadG
EM3-A-GLOMAP_AEROCOM-A2-CTRL_r0i0p0.nc" ;
```

Comment: You can use some algorithm like `contourf` or `imshow`  interpolate where you don't have data...

Comment: It seems a bit like the polygons crossing the dateline are 'warping' 360deg around and intersecting with themselves. But hard to be sure without knowing what the data actually looks like. Is it public data?

Comment: Side note: you could use the "Save file" button instead of taking a screenshot.

Comment: Cheers guys:

Saullo, have made an imshow, it has complete coverage of all areas when put in a simple x-y grid and plotted without the map.

Rutger: It's not public data, but it's a NetCDF file for black carbon surface concentrations. The specifications are now in the question.

Comment: Just to be sure: have you checked by any chance to see if your data has small negative values? By using the LogLocator() your data should all be positive, otherwise the negative values won't be plotted... also... have you tried plotting without LogLocator()? do you still get blank spots?

Comment: razvanc - The data is all positive, with a minimum value of 7E-15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

The issue was with the loop getting the data from a 0-360 latitude setting to a -180 to 180. As it did this, it left the latitudes correct but not in a monotonically increasing order (180 to 1.25, then skipped from -178.75 going up to 0)

This, in addition with the cyclic nature, caused points to be plotted and then the contours to match data the 0 (last latitude) and 180 (first one) together, which are of course, plotted halfway across from one another.

To get round this, I merely sorted the lat line, and rejigged the data to match the newly sorted latitudes.

```
lon = sorted(lon)


bc1 = bc[:,0:97]
bc2 = bc[:,97:]

bc = np.hstack((bc2,bc1))
```

This recreated the data and latitudes in the correct order and prevented the plotting error.